# Defining multiplication and differentiation in a dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $B$ be a space of complex-valued analytic functions from some compact subset $C$ of $\mathbb{C}^n.$ $B$ is a Banach space with the uniform norm.

Now, the paper I am reading says that we would need the dual space $B'$ of $B$. In this space, it says to "define differentiation and multiplication by transposition."

**Question: What does this mean?**

I really have no idea. All I know is that $B'$ is the (Banach) space of continuous linear functionals on $B$. I am also familiar with the transpose of a linear map but I'm not sure how this allows us to define multiplication and differentiation.

Are there alternative definitions/constructions I am not aware of?

Comment: It probably means that if you want to define $\phi'$ for $\phi$ in the dual, you do it by setting $\phi'(f):=\phi(f')$, i.e. you transpose the derivation to the function inside. It is often used the notation $\left<\phi,f\right>$ to denote $\phi(f)$. Then the prime is jumping from one side to the other in this notation. Representing the functionals by integrals the 'transposition' occurs using integration by parts. A boundary term may be necessary. If $A$ is a linear operator and $\left<,\right>$ is the inner product, then $A$ jumps to the other side as transpose.

Comment: If I define it this way, can I establish a relationship between the elements in $B$ and the elements in $B'$? From what I can infer from the article, there seems to be some kind of correspondence between elements of $B$ and $B'$ in a way that their norms are related (probably equal?). And what about multiplication?

Comment: If $B$ is an algebra then you can multiply $\varphi \in B'$ with elements of $B$ by $(f\varphi)(g)= \varphi(fg)$.

Comment: If $B$ is an algebra then you can multiply $\varphi \in B'$ with elements of $B$ by $(f\varphi)(g)= \varphi(fg)$. This defines an element of $B'$ if $M_f:B\to B$, $g \to fg$ is continuous (which usually follows from the closed graph theorem, e.g., if the norm of $B$ is stronger than the uniform norm on $C$). This multiplication $B'\to B'$ is in fact the transposed of $M_f$. For a multiplication $B'\times B'\to B'$ one would probably need much stronger assumptions.